# Movie where Peter Lorre asks, "Can I kill him? Can I kill him now, boss?"

Tags: identify-this-movie, dialogue

I know this is a bit on the trivial end, but I'm trying to locate a movie for reference in something I'm writing.  I know I've seen this somewhere, and I can't place it.  I don't think I saw the entire movie, probably just a scene or two.

I remember seeing Peter Lorre asking something like, "Can I kill him?  Can I kill him now, boss?"

I've looked on Google and found one comment that indicates it may be in *The Sad Sack*, and I have ordered it, but I don't know when it will arrive and the one place I saw that stated sounded like the author wasn't positive it was from that movie -- and I really can't keep watching every movie someone *thinks* contained that line.

Does anyone know where that line came from?

Comment: According to Imdb, he's only been in about 112 movies, just keep watching!

Comment: Can you remember if it was a comedy/thriller or something else?

Comment: For some reason I want to say it's from The Maltese Falcon (1941), but it's been a while since I saw it.

Comment: @Nobby: Definitely not _The Maltese Falcon_!  I just watched that a few months ago.

Comment: @Advicer: I really wish I knew more about it.  I just finished watching _Arsenic and the Old Lace_ because a friend said it was in there.  While I enjoyed the movie, as AidanO pointed out, I can't watch all 112 movies he made!  (A friend also tells me it was a movie he was in with James Cagney -- everyone has a different suggestion!)

Comment: Aarghh ! I remember seeing this too but I can't come up with it. I think, however, that we can narrow the 112 movies down to 20. I've pretty much ruled all but these. Perhaps others can further narrow down the list. 1940 You'll Find Out, 1950 Double Confession, 1949 Rope of Sand, 1947 My Favorite Brunette, 1946 The Chase, 1946 Black Angel, 1944 The Conspirators, (1944 Arsenic and Old Lace ? - I know you said you just watched this but...), 1943 Background to Danger, 1941 All Through the Night, 1941 The Face Behind the Mask, 1940 Stranger on the Third Floor, 1940 Island of Doomed Men, 1940 Stran

Comment: @GlennFerrell: So you're sure it's not _The Sad Sack_?  I can verify it is NOT _Arsenic and Old Lace_.  I just watched that last night.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right! It is Sad Sack and [here is the clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoiu0r8SPFw).   The line is "Please, can I kill him now?"

I had rejected that because the image of Peter Lorre I had was a much younger, leaner version -- so I ruled out all movies after about '55.

Perhaps this is not the only movie he said this line in... :)

Comment: I wish you had posted that about 50 minutes earlier -- I just got through watching _Sad Sack_.  (It's quite lacking in many ways!)  I had thought it was on normal Netflix, but saw it was on streaming.  I had intended to watch or listen while packing up for an event tomorrow, but was tired and sat through it all.  (It wasn't worth it!)  On Netflix, that line is about 1:20 (as in 1 hour, 20 minutes) in, and it's repeated within 2 minutes and repeated again at about 1:34 or so by another character.  So that's it - thanks for your help! (Just wish it was early enough so I didn't watch that movie!)

Comment: By the way, any chance it was used elsewhere?  Maybe _Sad Sack_ used it as a reference?

Comment: I suspect "Sad Sack" may be a parody of an earlier use. I was lucky, by the way, Sad Sack is broken up into many clips on Youtube and I just picked the highest numbered one - that's where I found the comment. I don't remember ever seeing this movie before. Thanks for the heads up not to watch it :)

Comment: I haven't seen much of Jerry Lewis, but as a competitive ballroom dancer, I was interested in his fight scene (that was also comic) since it was almost like a dance, but there is no real plot and the whole spy thing didn't even start until about 10 minutes or so before the line in question.  I guess a Jerry Lewis fan might want to see it, but otherwise, it's plotless, nothing memorable in the writing and pointless.  I agree there's a chance the use of the line in _Sad Sack_ may be a parody -- which makes me wonder where it was originally used.  But searching produced no other references.

Comment: Well - if a parody - it's not in "Strange Cargo" or "You'll Find Out". Just saw those on YouTube. "You'll Find Out" is a comedy - kind of entertaining if you like 40s big band music, Karloff & Bela Lugosi.

Comment: As a competitive ballroom dancer, I get a lot of big band music when I'm on the dance floor.  Just love it.  I'll have to check that out!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for it too. I thought it was with Humphrey Bogart in Casablanca but I can't find it, even after scanning scripts. Curious that it's blatantly missing.